Chocolatey CLI v2.2.2 prompts for credentials when trying to install ROS
I've followed every step in this tutorial https://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows installing vs 2019 and all required packages and after pasting
choco upgrade ros-noetic-desktop_full -y --execution-timeout=0 to install the package
I was prompted for my credentials. If I enter nothing I get a 403 Authentication error
This isn't the expected behaviour and nobody else in my lab was able to reproduce the issue even when using the same operating system (windows 11) and the same network. I'm kind of at a loss as to why this is happening. I've changed network and reinstalled everything. The error persisted and even appeared when I tried to reinstall Git. (altought it still installed after failing to authenticate but not for ros noetic)
